# For loop adding undefined entry's

Tags: javascript

I'm using a couple of for loops to create an array.  Problem is, on the second pass it adds 4 undefined variables and I can't see where they're coming from.

Note: the if statement is correct and only gets fired when they match.

The code :

```
for (var x = 0; x < galleryObject[1].length; x++) {
    gallerys[x]= [];    

    for (var i = 0; i < galleryObject[2].length; i++) {

        if (galleryObject[2][i].galId === galleryObject[1][x].id) {


            gallerys[x][i] = {};
            gallerys[x][i].filename=galleryObject[2][i].fileName
            gallerys[x][i].caption =galleryObject[2][i].caption


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: try to check before adding in alert

Comment: Yeah, I've added console.log's everywhere, I can't see why it isn't working.

Comment: then there is an error exist in your code.try to put all the code in comments and then try removing the comments line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the problem here in the fact that sometimes your IF statements returns false. In that case it tries to add an element to an array but some previous indexes are not specified, so it fills them with 'undefined'.

Try to change your code in the IF statement to:

```
    if (galleryObject[2][i].galId === galleryObject[1][x].id) {
        gallerys.push({
                          filename:galleryObject[2][i].fileName,
                          caption :galleryObject[2][i].caption
                      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  You might want to change those `=` to `:` and remove that extra `)` though ;)